# Keep contacts local (not google account related already disabled) from other accounts on phone ie hotmail

Tags: contacts, nexus-5

I've had my nexus 5 for a while now and still haven't found a solution to the particular problem I am having, I want to keep all of my phone contacts local without syncing them to an account, now I've disabled Google Contacts Sync, which stops the phone syncing contacts to a google account, however when using any other account with the built in email application (either corporate, imap or POP3) it begins asking me to sync contacts with that account. It is frustrating to say the least, any insights that you guys might have would be really valued as another question showed me how to disable Google Contacts Sync!

Edit - if its any use I think it as attempting to sync with something related to exchange.

Comment: You can select what to sync for an account by going to Settings -> Accounts & Sync -> [your account]. You should have the Sync settings screen open, and from there you can deselect Contacts, and the syncing will stop. (Someone can elaborate on this as an answer, but since I don't have my Android device handy, this is more of a guideline comment than an accurate answer)

Comment: Thanks for your input, I've tried that as well, but even with contacts sync off, it still asks me everytime i try to make a new contact

Answer (score 1):

[MyLocalAccount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.mylocalaccount) adds an entirely local account to your account-list. Within the dialogue for creating a new contact, you can choose the contact to be created into that account.

Comment: @Frustrated: Did my hint help?